# Has anyone got any experience using Pfeed? I have several issues to build up a 'recent activity' log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I have started trying to use [Pfeed plugin](http://github.com/parolkar/pfeed) for my Rails app. Apart from four support pages of wiki on the Github, I only found [this blog post](http://www.travisdunn.com/activity-logs-and-friend-feeds-on-rails-pfeed/comment-page-1) helpful for me to start using.

I have managed to get the simple feeds working like "User bought 12 items about 1 minute ago" etc. But when it comes to [customize the feed items](http://wiki.github.com/parolkar/pfeed/customizing-the-pfeed-item), that's where I have having issues to proceed. Pfeed uses Model&View items for each feed configuration and I found out that models are working as it should be. Very frustrating.

Has anyone used this Plugin before? If so, please do let me know how it goes. Also if you have ever used any other good plugins for this sort of Recent Activity feature, please show me the way.

### Many thanks.

Phyo

Comment: any luck, I have ben finding it dificult to use too

Comment: I am working on custom feed item and facing some data required error while saving the pfeed record which wasn't supposed to be. @phyo, @angela - any specific problem that you guys are facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it's the answer you're looking for, but I looked through a bunch of timeline generators and settled for [`timeline_fu`](https://github.com/jamesgolick/timeline_fu)

It's quite easy to use (I ended up forking it and making some edits so save some extra variables etc. but it was really easy to do).

Comment: It's been a while the question has been asked. That plugin seems nice, so I'll accept it. Thanks.